# Full screen overlay for website

Tags: html, css, overlay

So I want an overlay (red) that covers the whole page, and is on top of everything. I also would like it to be possible to click through it, and have elements below it act as if the overlay isn't there.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show us your attempts first and share with us code that you have tried so far.

Comment: show what you have tried for this

Comment: If he don't have any idea of making it. How he will try

Comment: @SanthoshKumar google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:#000;
  opacity:.3;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

</div>
<div>
  You will be able to see the content. But cant click it
</div>
```

Make sure that `.overlay` is appended as direct child to the `body` tag

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/86XkHcz8G5Z7vCMJh5gs?p=preview

Use an overlay div with position: absolute property to cover entire page.

Use `pointer-events: none;` to make the overlay clickable.

**html**

```
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<div>
  You can click through the overlay. Try clicking here <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Visit Google</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  position:relative;
  height: 2000px;
}
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
  pointer-events: none; // This will allow you to click through overlay
}
```